# Error en JPA Y ECLIPSELINK error de mapeo de datos

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Estoy trabajando un `crud` en `java jpa` y `eclipselink`, una tabla **notas** está relacionada con **alumno, docente, curso**. Cuando quiero insertar un nuevo registro de notas me manda el siguiente error:

> Error no se guardo During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: SEGUNDO JESUS.

**entidad notas**: esta tiene todas sus relaciones y entidades ya generadas:

```java
package com.sistema.colegio.Pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


@Entity
@Table(name="notas")
@NamedQuery(name="Nota.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM Nota n")
public class Nota implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private String codigo;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fecha;

    private byte[] foto;

    private double nota;

    private String tema;

    private String unidad;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ALUMNO", referencedColumnName = "IdAlumno")
    private Alumno alumnoBean;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Curso
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CURSO", referencedColumnName = "IdCurso")
    private Curso cursoBean;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Docente
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PROFESOR", referencedColumnName = "IdDocente")
    private Docente docente;

    public Nota() {
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return this.fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public byte[] getFoto() {
        return this.foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public double getNota() {
        return this.nota;
    }

    public void setNota(double nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    public String getTema() {
        return this.tema;
    }

    public void setTema(String tema) {
        this.tema = tema;
    }

    public String getUnidad() {
        return this.unidad;
    }

    public void setUnidad(String unidad) {
        this.unidad = unidad;
    }

    public Alumno getAlumnoBean() {
        return this.alumnoBean;
    }

    public void setAlumnoBean(Alumno alumnoBean) {
        this.alumnoBean = alumnoBean;
    }

    public Curso getCursoBean() {
        return this.cursoBean;
    }

    public void setCursoBean(Curso cursoBean) {
        this.cursoBean = cursoBean;
    }

    public Docente getDocente() {
        return this.docente;
    }

    public void setDocente(Docente docente) {
        this.docente = docente;
    }

}
```

**entidad alumno**: esta entidad está relacionada con notas, un alumno puede tener muchas notas:

```
package com.sistema.colegio.Pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Alumno.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Alumno a")
public class Alumno implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="IdAlumno")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private String idAlumno;

    private String apellido;

    private int celular;

    private String correo;

    private String direccion;

    private int dni;

//  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="fech_nac")
    private String fechNac;

//  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="fech_reg")
    private String fechReg;

    private byte[] foto;

    private String grado;

    private String nombre;

    private String sexo;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="alumnoBean",cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Nota> notas;

    public Alumno() {
    }

    public String getIdAlumno() {
        return this.idAlumno;
    }

    public void setIdAlumno(String idAlumno) {
        this.idAlumno = idAlumno;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return this.apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public int getCelular() {
        return this.celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(int celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return this.correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return this.direccion;
    }**texto en negrita**

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public int getDni() {
        return this.dni;
    }

    public void setDni(int dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getFechNac() {
        return this.fechNac;
    }

    public void setFechNac(String fechNac) {
        this.fechNac = fechNac;
    }

    public String getFechReg() {
        return this.fechReg;
    }

    public void setFechReg(String fechReg) {
        this.fechReg = fechReg;
    }

    public byte[] getFoto() {
        return this.foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getGrado() {
        return this.grado;
    }

    public void setGrado(String grado) {
        this.grado = grado;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return this.sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public List<Nota> getNotas() {
        return this.notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(List<Nota> notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    public Nota addNota(Nota nota) {
        getNotas().add(nota);
        nota.setAlumnoBean(this);

        return nota;
    }

    public Nota removeNota(Nota nota) {
        getNotas().remove(nota);
        nota.setAlumnoBean(null);

        return nota;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [idAlumno=" + idAlumno + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", celular=" + celular + ", correo=" + correo
                + ", direccion=" + direccion + ", dni=" + dni + ", fechNac=" + fechNac + ", fechReg=" + fechReg
                + ", foto=" + Arrays.toString(foto) + ", grado=" + grado + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", sexo=" + sexo
                + ", notas=" + notas + "]";
    }


}
```

**entidad docente**: esta entidad está relacionada con notas porque un docente puede poner una nota a varios alumnos:

```java
package com.sistema.colegio.Pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Docente.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Docente d")
public class Docente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="IdDocente")
    private String idDocente;

    private String apellido;

    private int celular;

    private String correo;

    private String direccion;

    private int dni;


    @Column(name="fech_nac")
    private Date fechNac;


    @Column(name="fech_reg")
    private Date fechReg;

    @Column(name="grado_inst")
    private String gradoInst;

    private String nombre;

    private String profesion;

    private String sexo;

    @Lob
    private byte[] foto;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="docente",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Nota> notas;

    public Docente() {
    }

    public String getIdDocente() {
        return this.idDocente;
    }

    public void setIdDocente(String idDocente) {
        this.idDocente = idDocente;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return this.apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public int getCelular() {
        return this.celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(int celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return this.correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return this.direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public int getDni() {
        return this.dni;
    }

    public void setDni(int dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Date getFechNac() {
        return this.fechNac;
    }

    public void setFechNac(Date fechNac) {
        this.fechNac = fechNac;
    }

    public Date getFechReg() {
        return this.fechReg;
    }

    public void setFechReg(Date fechReg) {
        this.fechReg = fechReg;
    }

    public byte[] getFoto() {
        return this.foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getGradoInst() {
        return this.gradoInst;
    }

    public void setGradoInst(String gradoInst) {
        this.gradoInst = gradoInst;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getProfesion() {
        return this.profesion;
    }

    public void setProfesion(String profesion) {
        this.profesion = profesion;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return this.sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public List<Nota> getNotas() {
        return this.notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(List<Nota> notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    public Nota addNota(Nota nota) {
        getNotas().add(nota);
        nota.setDocente(this);

        return nota;
    }

    public Nota removeNota(Nota nota) {
        getNotas().remove(nota);
        nota.setDocente(null);

        return nota;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  idDocente + apellido  + celular  + direccion + dni  + fechNac + fechReg
                + gradoInst + nombre  + profesion  + sexo
                + Arrays.toString(foto)  + notas  ;
    }


}
```

**entidad curso**: esta entidad está relacionada con curso porque curso puede tener una o varias notas y un alumno puede tener varios cursos:

```java
package com.sistema.colegio.Pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Curso.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Curso c")
public class Curso implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="IdCurso")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private String idCurso;

    private String nombre;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cursoBean",cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Nota> notas;

    public Curso() {
    }

    public String getIdCurso() {
        return this.idCurso;
    }

    public void setIdCurso(String idCurso) {
        this.idCurso = idCurso;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public List<Nota> getNotas() {
        return this.notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(List<Nota> notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    public Nota addNota(Nota nota) {
        getNotas().add(nota);
        nota.setCursoBean(this);

        return nota;
    }

    public Nota removeNota(Nota nota) {
        getNotas().remove(nota);
        nota.setCursoBean(null);

        return nota;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  nombre ;
    }



}
```

**controlador notas**: este controlador tiene todos los métodos de `jpa`

```
package com.sistema.colegio.Controlador;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.sistema.colegio.Pojo.Alumno;
import com.sistema.colegio.Pojo.Curso;
import com.sistema.colegio.Pojo.Nota;
import com.sistema.colegio.Util.JPA_UTIL;

public class NotasModel {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =Logger.getLogger("com.sistema.colegio.Controlador.DocenteModel");

    public void InsertarNotas(Nota n) {
        EntityManager manager=null;
        try {
            manager=JPA_UTIL.getEntityManager();
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.persist(n);
            //manager.persist(a);
            manager.flush();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Mensaje Guardado");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "EXITO !!  DATOS  GUARDADOS", "MENSSAGE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();

            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error no se guardo"+e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR !! DATOS NO GUARDADOS", "MENSSAGE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    public void ModificarNotas(Nota n) {
        EntityManager manager=null;
        try {

            manager=JPA_UTIL.getEntityManager();
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.merge(n);
            manager.flush();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Mensaje Modificado");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "EXITO !!  DATOS  MODIFICADOS", "MENSSAGE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error no se Modificó");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR !! DATOS NO MODIFICADOS", "MENSSAGE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }finally {
            manager.close();
        }

    }

    public void EliminarNotas(String id) {
            EntityManager manager=null;
        try {
            manager=JPA_UTIL.getEntityManager();
            Nota no=manager.find(Nota.class, id);
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.remove(no);
            manager.flush();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Mensaje ELIMINADO");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error no se Elimino");
        }finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    public void ListarCombo(JComboBox<Curso>cboCurso) {
        EntityManager manager=JPA_UTIL.getEntityManager();
        Iterator it=manager.createQuery("select n from Curso n").getResultList().iterator();
        Curso  c;
        try {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                c= (Curso) it.next();
                cboCurso.addItem(c);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error no se pudo listar");
        }
    }

}
```

**formulario**: este es el botón guardar. El error es de ahí, cuando quiero guardar una nota con un alumno, un profesor y curso que se relacionan sale el error. Me pueden ayudar por favor, soy nuevo en eso.

```
protected void actionPerformedBtnGuardar(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(txtAlumno.getText().equals("")|| txtNota.getText().equals("")||txtProfesor.getText().equals("")||
                txtTema.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"POR FAVOR !!! "+"\n completar todos los campos","ADVERTECNIA",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }else {
            /*CAMPOS DE OTRAS TABLAS*/
            Alumno a=new Alumno();
            a.setNombre(txtAlumno.getText());

            Docente d=new Docente();
            d.setNombre(txtProfesor.getText());

            Curso c=new Curso();
            c.setNombre(txtAlumno.getText());

            Nota ns=new Nota();
            ns.setCodigo(txtCodigo.getText());
            ns.setAlumnoBean(a);
            ns.setDocente(d);
            ns.setCursoBean(c);
            ns.setTema(txtTema.getText());
            ns.setUnidad(cboUnidad.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ns.setNota(Double.parseDouble(txtNota.getText()));
            ns.setFecha(new java.sql.Date(dtFecha.getDate().getTime()));
            n.InsertarNotas(ns);
        }
    }

    private void ListarCombo (JComboBox cboCurso) {
        n.ListarCombo(cboCurso);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es que no tienes definida la relación de dependencia para JPA:

```
        Alumno a=new Alumno();
        a.setNombre(txtAlumno.getText());

        Docente d=new Docente();
        d.setNombre(txtProfesor.getText());

        Curso c=new Curso();
        c.setNombre(txtAlumno.getText());

        Nota ns=new Nota();
        ns.setCodigo(txtCodigo.getText());

        ns.setAlumnoBean(a);
        ns.setDocente(d);
        ns.setCursoBean(c);
        //...
        n.InsertarNotas(ns);
```

Has creado un nuevo alumno, un nuevo docente y un nuevo curso (ninguno de los tres tiene un ID asignado). Cuando quieres guardar la nota, se encuentra que la has asociado con otras tres entidades que desconoce y no sabe qué hacer.

Dependiendo de lo que realmente quieras hacer los pasos serían:

- Si alguna de las tres entidades (Alumno, Docente y Curso) existen previamente, no crees objetos nuevos, obtenlas de la base de datos y rellena la nota con ellas.
- Si quieres que se cree la nueva entidad, entonces debes marcar la **acción en cascada** a realizar para esa relación. Por ejemplo, si quieres que se cree el Alumno, sería algo como:

  ```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, name="ALUMNO", referencedColumnName = "IdAlumno")
  private Alumno alumnoBean;
  ```